# jQuery reload browser window only between specific browser width

Tags: jquery, resize, window, refresh, reload

I am using this bit of code successfully:

```
$(window).bind('resize',function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```

But my problem is, I only want to reload / refresh the window when scaling between 320px and 480px. If I resize between 480px and 960px for example, I do not need the window to reload, so I need to find a way to restrict this to <= 480px I guess.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

**EDIT BELOW**

In response to Kolink:

Okay, so I sort of got it working using this:

```
$(window).bind('resize',function() {

    var winWidth = $(window).width();

    if (winWidth < 480) {

        window.location.href = window.location.href;

    } 
    else {
        // nothing
    }

});
```

Problem is now, it is constantly reloading on the iphone. If I go from portrait to landscape on the iphone, it just keeps reloading over and over again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pages that reload after resize give a horrible user experience - in my opinion. What about using a reponsive layout like zurb foundation or twitter bootstrap use.

Comment: I agree about the reloading after resize, but I don't see any other solution to my problem. My site is responsive, and its using jQuery Masonry. Basically, for 320px users my columnWidth needs to be 160px where as everything above that is 240px. I have solved changing the column width, but the problem is, this doesn't get updated until the window is reloaded... so thats why I am trying to figure out this resizing function. My columnWidth line looks like this: columnWidth : $(window).width() > 480 ? 240 : 160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple `if` statement, checking the size of the window and only reloading if necessary.